# visudo don't apply modifications

Tags: server, sudo, visudo

i'm on ubuntu server
I'm trying to use a command

```
sudo /usr/binsystemctl start myscript.service
```

Without password. i want this command execute without ask password.

I used

```
sudo visudo
```

and writed :

```
peon ALL =NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl restart myscript.service
peon ALL =NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl start myscript.service
peon ALL =NOPASSWD: /usb/bin/systemctl stop myscript.service
peon ALL =NOPASSWD: /usb/bin/systemctl
peon ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/systemctl /usr/sbin/reboot
```

I tryed :

```
 peon ALL =NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl restart myscript.service,/usr/bin/systemctl start myscript.service,/usb/bin/systemctl stop myscript.service
```

But everytime i use this command on a bash terminal, ubuntu ask me for password.

Comment: Hopefully it's just a typo in the question, but your first command starts with: `sudo /usr/binsystemctl ...` instead of `sudo /usr/bin/systemctl ...`.

Comment: Does your sudoers file have later rules for your user, perhaps a catch-all that allows any command but *with* a password (*without* a NOPASSWD flag)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, after some try i founded a solution....

First i puted my command in the LAST line of visudo
not in the middle.

Second :
I used this syntax :

```
peon ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl restart myscript.service
```